# Firebase - Error code 24 after trying to use Facebook login in Ionic app

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, facebook-login

I'm trying to use Firebase to login in Facebook in my Ionic application. Every step works fine, I can input my Facebook account and password, the app browser redirects back to the Firebase domain, but when the Firebase page finishes loading, it doesn't return to the app, it instead remains in the app browser with a blank page showing this error:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code":503,
        "message":"Error code: 24",
        "errors":[{
            "message":"Error code: 24",
            "domain":"global",
            "reason":"backendError"
        }]
    }
}
```

I'm using a browser and not the cordova plugin for Facebook because I've tried it already and other errors came out for unknown reasons.

I followed the steps described in this tutorial:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=stxCOBr5d8o

Also, I haven't found any reference to this error code here or in any other site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a update.

It seems there is a Service Disruption in Firebase Authentication.
Please check https://status.firebase.google.com/incident/Authentication/18003.

---

I have a experience got 503-error before by the whitelist issue of Dynamic Links.

In the configuration of the guide, Cordova authentication seems using the Dynamic Links. 
 https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/cordova#set_up_firebase_authentication_for_cordova

I think the 503 error occurred because the fallback link after sign-in via the Dynamic Links link is not included in the Whitelist URL pattern.

So, try to specify the URL patterns allowed in your deep link and fallback links using regular expressions.
[image]

Comment: hmm I tried adding a regex pattern that accepts anything (.*) for testing, but it didn't work either

Comment: Looks like a bug. Please check https://status.firebase.google.com/incident/Authentication/18003